# Configure script failed to find C compiler, despite gcc being installed on Sabayon

Tags: gcc, configure, compiler, sabayon

I have been trying to compile Moksha from source code on a Sabayon SpinBase Virtual Machine, but whenever I run a configure or autogen.sh script I get an error:

```
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... no
```

I have installed [libc](https://packages.sabayon.org/show/libc,71536,sabayon-weekly,amd64,5,standard) too.

Comment: We'll need some actual details. A reasonable start would be the `config.log` that should contain the commands that were executed to check the above. Please post that. Also, specify if things are installed in non-standard places. Running `.configure` with a `--verbose` flag is also worth trying.

Comment: @FaheemMitha If you know a way of me getting that config.log file to you, I'll be happy to hear it. Remember I'm using the SpinBase version of Sabayon: there's no clipboard, or graphical user interface at all with the SpinBase edition and hence I cannot simply open up a web browser in my VM and post the config.log file.

Comment: Presumably you have network access on your VM. Can you email or copy the log to another machine? Then you can post from that other machine.